# nftables, accept policy, given TCP port, LAN machines only

Tags: debian, firewall, nftables

This is a `nftables` beginner question.

Given the rule:

```
iifname $NIC_NAME tcp dport 22 accept
```

in the `chain_input` chain below:

```
table inet table_inet {
    chain chain_input {
        type filter hook input priority 0
        iif lo accept
        icmp type echo-request accept
        ct state established,related accept
        iifname $NIC_NAME tcp dport 22 accept
        policy drop
    }
    chain chain_output {
        type filter hook output priority 0
        policy accept
    }
    chain chain_forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0
        policy drop
    }
}
```

how can I modify this rule so that only packets with an IP in the same LAN are accepted?
With `iptables` I used the option `-m iprange --src-range 192.168.4.1-192.168.4.254` for the LAN `192.168.4.0/24`.
I hope my question is clear enough.

EDIT 1

I propose:

```
iifname $NIC_NAME tcp dport 22 ip saddr 192.168.4.0/24 accept
```

With the `accept` policy, I can connect to the SSH server, with the `drop` policy, I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed

```
iifname $NIC_NAME tcp dport 22 ip saddr 192.168.4.0/24 accept
```

seems correct to me.